# How to download SSIS Packages from SSISDB

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2014

I'm still fairly new to SSIS.  I've figured out how to download packages from a server by connecting to Integration Services.  How do I download packages from SSISDB?  Background: We have a TON of packages that the previous people created.  All packages SHOULD be kept in the same folder structure on our shared drive.  However, there are cases where the package that is in the database is newer than the one on the shared drive.  I want to be able to look at the installed packages to see if they match what's on the shared drive, and if the installed version is newer edit that version.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are a couple of options to download packages (projects) from the SSISDB http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2016/04/get-packages-from-ssis-catalog.html

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks very much!!